# Density of Solution to ODE in Function Space

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Let $d$ be a positive integer.  Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{d+1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$   and $g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, be once continuously differentiable functions and define the solution map $\Phi(t,x)$ to the (family of) initial value problems
$$
\begin{aligned}
\partial_t \Phi(t,x) &= f(t,\Phi(t,x))\\
\Phi(0,x)&\triangleq g(x).
\end{aligned}
$$

Is there a theorem characterizing $f$, such that the set $X$ defined by:
$$
X\triangleq \left\{
g(x) : (\exists t \in [0,\infty)) g(x)=\Phi(t,x) (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d)
\right\},
$$
is dense in $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\Phi$ satisfies
$$
\Phi(t,x)\circ \Phi(s,x)= \Phi(t+s,x)
, (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d).
$$

If this is not possible, is there a theorem discussing a "reasonable" Borel-measure $\mu$ on $C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\{f^n\}$ is $\mu$-almost everywhere dense?

**Note:** $C(\mathbb{R}^d;\mathbb{R}^d)$ is considered with the compact-open topology.

Comment: Hi, you have used the same symbol $f$ for an homeomorphism and a $C^1$ function: could you correct the notation in order to make clearer the question?

Comment: Sorry about that.  All fixed :)